# How to convert degree minutes second into decimal in java

Tags: java

This is a basically gps application where i am getting the latitude information from the meta data of a picture in this format 28"41'44.13597 .

My need is to convert the same information into decimal and the out will show data in decimal format like 28.705450.

Please help through code or any references

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
/** answer=hour+minutes/60+seconds/3600 */
public double convertHourToDecimal(String degree) { 
    if(!degree.matches("(-)?[0-6][0-9]\"[0-6][0-9]\'[0-6][0-9](.[0-9]{1,5})?")
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    String[] strArray=degree.split("[\"']");
    return Double.parseDouble(strArray[0])+Double.parseDouble(strArray[1])/60+Double.parseDouble(strArray[2])/3600;
}
```

Comment: If you want to make sure the data is formatted correctly, shouldn't the program check to make sure " follows the degrees and ' follows the minutes?

Comment: The format checking code does not work (68"62'65.9 passes, but -82"30'0. fails).

Comment: Thanks. I simplified the regexp to this: "-?\\d+\\\"\\d{2}\\'\\d{1,2}.?\\d*". Also, don't forget to multiply by -1 if latRef=S or lngRef=W

Answer (score 6):

Divide the minutes by `60.` and the seconds by `3600.`, then add the three together.

Answer (score 6):

I dont know of any java library that will do this for you but the formula to convert from degrees to decimal degrees is:
degree + (minutes / 60) + (seconds / (60 * 60))

Answer (score -1):

```
package newstract;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Date;
import com.drew.imaging.jpeg.JpegMetadataReader;
import com.drew.metadata.Directory;
import com.drew.metadata.Metadata;
import com.drew.metadata.exif.ExifDirectory;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import com.drew.metadata.exif.GpsDirectory;

public class GetTagInfo {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Picture Tagged Details");
        try{
        File jpegFile = new File("DSC_0060.JPG"); 
        Metadata metadata = JpegMetadataReader.readMetadata(jpegFile);
        Directory exifDirectory = metadata.getDirectory(ExifDirectory.class);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        Date myDate = exifDirectory.getDate(ExifDirectory.TAG_DATETIME); 
        System.out.println(sdf.format(myDate));  
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date myDate1 = exifDirectory.getDate(ExifDirectory.TAG_DATETIME); 
        System.out.println(sdf1.format(myDate1));  
        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
        Date myDate3 = exifDirectory.getDate(ExifDirectory.TAG_DATETIME); 
        System.out.println(sdf2.format(myDate3));  


        Directory gpsDirectory = metadata.getDirectory(GpsDirectory.class);
       // Boolean b = (gpsDirectory.containsTag(GpsDirectory.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE));
       // System.out.println(GpsDirectory.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);+
        String s = gpsDirectory.getDescription(2);
        System.out.println(s);
        SplitString1 w = new SplitString1();
        w.doit(s);



        Iterator directories = metadata.getDirectoryIterator();
        while (directories.hasNext()) {
        GpsDescriptor directory = (GpsDescriptor) directories.next();
        System.out.print(directory.getGpsLatitudeDescription());
        }

        } // close of catch
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            //System.err.println(tag.getDirectoryName() + " " + tag.getTagName() + " (error)");
        }

}

}

 class SplitString1 {

    public void doit(String lat) {

        String str = lat;
        String [] temp = null;
        String dtemp = null;
        //temp = str.split("[\"]|\"[\']");
        temp = str.split("[\"]|[\']" ); 
        dtemp = str.replace("\"", "°");
        System.out.println("Formated DCM : "+dtemp);
        dump(temp);


    }

    public void dump(String []s) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < s.length ; i++) {
            System.out.println("\ndegree : "+s[0]);
            System.out.println("\nminutes : "+s[1]);
            System.out.println("\nsecond : "+s[2]);

            String deg = s[0] ;
            int ndeg = Integer.parseInt(deg);
            String min = s[1] ;
            double nmin = Double.parseDouble(min);
            String sec = s[2] ;
            double nsec = Double.parseDouble(sec);
            double decimaldms = (ndeg+(nmin/60)+(nsec/3600));
            System.out.println("\nfinaldecimal : "+decimaldms);
        }
    }

    // Decimal degrees = whole number of degrees, plus minutes divided by 60, 
    //plus seconds divided by 3600
}
```