# convert geo co-ordinates to display in android

Tags: android, geolocation

7°57'23.07"N

80°45'34.47"E

How do I convert this to display in microdegrees?

I have a mapview and want to display a point in that.

Comment: See this url for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779405/how-to-convert-degree-minutes-second-into-decimal-in-java

Comment: @niels is that accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first convert into the decimal value then convert into the geopoint I found from I post this to convert degrees to decimal

```
To convert the number of minutes to a decimal value, use the following formula:
Decimal value = Minutes/60
As an example, a longitude of 122 degrees 45 minutes North is equal to 122.75 degrees North.
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244951

for online testing http://transition.fcc.gov/mb/audio/bickel/DDDMMSS-decimal.html